# Using ES6 Maps for react-router, how can we tweak Map.get?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, maps, react-router-dom

I have created a map with `new Map()` to store my RR4 configuration in my app.

I want to access the values of `/countries/:id`, when I get `/countries/1`

```js
routesMap.get('/countries/1') 
// should return the same as to routesMap.get('/countries/:id')

routesMap.get('/countries/1/comments/20'); 
// should match routesMap.get('/countries/:countryId/comments/:id')
```

By creating a class from `Map`, how can I tweak the get so it become more intelligent to get my react-router-dom path ?

Comment: Create a parent component that wraps your react router and store the info that you need in a redux-state, or a react context, then retrieve this state in child components that need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple attempt would be something like the following

```js
class RouteMap extends Map {
  get(key) {
    let match;
    // exact match
    if (this.has(key)) return super.get(key);
    
    // not exact match, need to apply logic
    for (let route of this.keys()) {
      const reg = new RegExp(`^${route.replace(/:\w+/g,'\\w+')}$`);
      if (!match && reg.test(key)) match = route;
    }
    return super.get(match);
  }
}


const routesMap = new RouteMap();
routesMap.set('/countries/:id', 'just id')
routesMap.set('/countries/:countryId/comments/:id', 'id and country')


console.log(routesMap.get('/countries/:id'));
console.log(routesMap.get('/countries/1'));

console.log(routesMap.get('/countries/:countryId/comments/:id')); 
console.log(routesMap.get('/countries/1/comments/20'));
```

But might need further work to become more flexible, performant and handle edge cases like trailing / etc.